# Assign rownames to data frame

Tags: r

Asking a basic question, how do I convert "typeI" to "typeII" dataframe with given
row names c( Mazda RX4,Mazda RX4 Wag, Datsun 710 ,  Hornet 4 Drive , Hornet Sportabout, Valiant)
Suggestions.

```
"typeI" 
mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1

"typeII"
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the `rownames()` function.

```
# Here is data (and how it is built)
# notice I used rownames to strip existing names!
data <- head(mtcars)
rownames(data) <- NULL

# assigning row names
rownames(data) <- c("Mazda RX4", "Mazda RX4 Wag", "Datsun 710", 
                    "Hornet 4 Drive", "Hornet Sportabout", "Valiant")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `row.names<-` like below

```
df <- `row.names<-`(
  df,
  c("Mazda RX4", "Mazda RX4 Wag", "Datsun 710","Hornet 4 Drive", "Hornet Sportabout", "Valiant")
)
```

Comment: Why not just use straightforward `row.names(df) <- ...` syntax? This seems unnecessarily hard to read